# When Listening to Ctrl + B event, Bookmark tab shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am trying to implement <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for a `contenteditable` div which should make the text bold.

The only problem I'm getting is that when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is pressed, browser's bookmark tab appears.

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuw4y1rc/1/))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#editable').designMode = 'on';
    $('#editable').on('keyup', function(e) {
        console.log(e.which);
        if(e.which == 66 && e.ctrlKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('bold');
            document.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#editable {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#editable:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div>
```

Please help me find a way to disable that bookmark when I'm focussed inside that editable div.

Comment: which browser? fiddle works as expected in chrome/osx

Comment: works in chrome/win8

Comment: Ctrl+d is use for bookmark, you code is working fine

Comment: On my firefox on ubunut `Ctrl+b` is for bookmarks. I guess there are many other people who have the same shortcut for bookmarks.

Comment: then change your shortcut for bookmarks, is not your code fault

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ER9VD/12/

Comment: There's no need to implement this yourself. Ctrl/Cmd-B does this automatically in contenteditable elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this solution

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ER9VD/12/)

```js
var g_state = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').keydown( function ( eve ) {
        if (eve.which === 17) {
            eve.preventDefault();
            g_state = 1;
        }
        return true;
    });
    $('body').keyup( function ( eve ){
        if (eve.which === 17) {
            eve.preventDefault();
            g_state = 0;
        }
        return true;
    });
    $('body').keypress( function ( eve ) {
        eve.preventDefault();
        if (eve.ctrlKey && (eve.which === 78)) {
            alert("(eve.ctrl + 'n')");   
        }
        else {
            if (g_state && (eve.which === 78)) {
                alert("(ctrl tracking by key up/down + 'n', resetting)");
                g_state = 0;
            }
            else {
                if (eve.shiftKey && (eve.which === 78)) {
                    alert("(eve.shift + 'n')");   
                }
                else {
                    alert("pass");   
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hi Dangling Cruze,

Here there is no any rocket science , What we are doing here is to Prevent the event bubing. And stopping event to reach at web browser. 
The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancel-able, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.
In single term

For example, this can be useful when:

```
Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL

At the document level we are binding all main three event 
    keydown
    keyup    
    keypress

and identifying key combination as well to prevent some key combination that is being used by browser as well.
```

let me know if you require any further help

Comment: It works But, I can't understand what's happening there. Can you provide some explanation?

Comment: @DanglingCruze just give me some min , I m busy with some task, once done with that i will put explanation as well for your understanding.

Comment: @DanglingCruze let me know if u need more clarification, Mark this as answer if it helped you, so other can get benefit of this.

Comment: In the fiddle I provided in my question. I'd used prevent default as well. Why does then my code not work?

Comment: You have not used all event , you must also attached keypress event to get it work